# Animate databound tab item header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, .net-4.0

I have a databound tab control which contains `n` number of tabs. I have both a Header and Content template for the tab control. The header template contains a stackpanel with an image and `TextBlock`, the content template contains the `WebBrowser` control.

What I've been asked to do is animate (mainly fade in/out) the image while the browser is navigating. I can create and execute the storyboard in code behind, but i do knot how to access the header template based on the browser that is navigating. Is there a way to do this? Or possibly a way to do this from event triggers in the xaml?

**EDIT:**  Added XAML code. There's no real code behind right now other than the 'tabitem' class and collection pieces and the 'webbrowser' utility class i used to bind to the source property of the 'webbrowser' control which i've added as well. I haven't created the 'storyboard' yet because i'm unsure on how to go about it. The image in the "HeaderTemplate" datatemplate is the one i need to animate. I just through in some random tab items in the collections, that info is normally grabbed from a database.

**XAML:**

```
<Window...>

    <Window.Resources>
        <src:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter"/>        
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="TabListResource" ObjectType="{x:Type src:TabList}" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">           
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}" Height="16" Width="16" x:Name="imgHeader" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" Padding="5,0,0,0" x:Name="Header" />
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">           
                <WebBrowser src:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding Content}"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Name="webBrowser" Navigated="webBrowser_Navigated" Navigating="webBrowser_Navigating"/>            
        </DataTemplate>        
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel Name="dockMain">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TabListResource}}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}">
            <TabControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">                    
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                                <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                  Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Margin="2,2,2,0"
                                  IsItemsHost="true" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>                    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TabControl.Template>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**TabItemData:**

```
class TabItemData
    {
        private string _header;
        private string _content;
        private string _imageSource;

        public TabItemData(string header, string content, string imageSource)
        {
            _header = header;
            _content = content;
            _imageSource = String.Format(@"../Images/{0}",imageSource);
        }
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
        }
        public string Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
        }
        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return _imageSource; }
        }

    }
```

**TabItem Collection:**

```
    class TabList : ObservableCollection<TabItemData>
        {
            public TabList() : base()
            {

                Add(new TabItemData("Header 1", "url1", "img1.png"));
                Add(new TabItemData("Header 2", "url2", "img2.png"));
                Add(new TabItemData("Header 3", "url3", "img3.png"));            
            }
        }
```

**Webbrowser Utility:** for binding to the source property

```
    public static class WebBrowserUtility
        {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableSource", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserUtility), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableSourcePropertyChanged));

            public static string GetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj)
            {
                return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty);
            }

            public static void SetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
            {
                obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value);
            }

            public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
                if (browser != null)
                {
                    string uri = e.NewValue as string;
                    browser.Source = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri) ? new Uri(uri) : null;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please post your current code (both the XAML and code-behind).

Comment: Just did. Sorry I didn't have the code at hand when posting